# read MySQL db from pyodbc

Tags: pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a db in localhost, but it runs indefinitely.....

```
db_path=conn = pyodbc.connect(
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=localhost;'
    r'PORT=3306;'
    r'DATABASE=mydb;'
    r'UID=root;'
    r'PWD=mypwd'
    )
```

[image: my User DSN]

[image]

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a connection string for Microsoft SQL Server, and that won't work for MySQL. You should be using either

```
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}
```

or

```
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}
```

For more details on the other connection parameters that MySQL expects, look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html)